# use loop to query overpass api

Tags: python, api, loops, pandas, overpass-api

I have a csv file of bounding boxes, that I loaded using pandas in python. The dataframe is *df* and the column name is *coord*. Does anyone know how I could create a loop to pass the list to my overpass api query?

I tried this:

```
import time
import overpass
api = overpass.API(timeout=900)

coords = [df['coord'][0:10]]
for coord in coords:
    results =[]
    params =[]
    params = 'node["power"="generator"]'+coord+';out skel;'
    results = api.Get(params, responseformat="json")
    time.sleep(5.0)
```

However, I got a multiple requests error.

I also tried:

```
x={}
x = (api.Get(param) for param in params)
```

But that returned a python object ( `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x11755c0f8>`) and I need the data as json.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can we see some input data? And desired output? Some of us may not be familiar with overpass module but can help structure your the data.

Comment: Thanks!  The list of coordinates for the bboxes looks like:
 [(-30, 170, -20, 180), (-40, 110, -30, 120), (-10, 0, 0, 10), (30, 150, 40, 160,(0, 70, 10, 80), (10, 120, 20, 130),(-30, 130, -20, 140), (40, 20, 50, 30), (70, 60, 80, 70), (30, -160, 40, -150)]

The output is a nested dictionary: 
{"features": [{"geometry": {"coordinates": [116.261146, -33.3416006], "type": "Point"}, "id": 293906560, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}

Comment: @JuliaDills, please edit your question with the data. Don't use a comment for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of this wrong here mainly with your approach:

1. `coords = [df['coord'][0:10]]` is not required. You can replace that with a simpler `df['coord'].tolist()`
2. You are initializing `params` with an empty list and then immediately after with a string, why?
3. Your string to `params` is what is causing your difficulty. I would use the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) method of Python strings to impute the coords in the query. Doing this is safer because it handles type conversions and proper placement by itself. You cannot simply add a tuple of coordinates to a string and expect it to work. Try printing the string you are assigning `params` to in your code, and print the same line from my solution below and you will see the difference. Your code will raise the error `TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly`, which mine will not.

Here is a complete solution:

```
import time
import overpass
api = overpass.API(timeout=900)

for coord in df['coord'].tolist():
    params = 'node["power"="generator"]{c};out skel;'.format(c=coord)
    results = api.Get(params, responseformat="json")
    time.sleep(5.0)
```

---

Note that if you get an error with the request, please provide a full traceback in your question. That will help us narrow down the real cause of the error.